# Redraw or delete the existing canvas and create a new one with modified content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to delete the existing canvas and create a new one with the modified content (of the old one).

Below is the code I have tried.

/* Identifying the Canvas child inside the div parent */

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvasDiv"),
canv = '',
cv = '';

for (i = 0; i < c.childElementCount; i++) {
        console.log(c.children[i].nodeName);
        if (c.children[i].nodeName == "CANVAS") {
        //console.log(c.children[i].getContext('2d'));
            canv = c.children[i];
            cv = c.children[i].getContext('2d');
        }
}



var new_cv = cv
var items = new_cv.canvas.aa.nodes.bi.ud

var keys = []
```

/* Retrieving the keys */

```
    for (var i in items){
    //console.log(items[i].value.Zd["key"]);
    keys.push(i + "|" +items[i].value.Zd["key"]);
}
```

/* Modifying the Content */

```
  for (var i in items){
    var strVal = items[i].value.Zd["key"];
    //console.log(items[i].value.Zd["key"]);
    for (var j in keys){
        if(items[i].value.Zd["key"] && items[i].value.Zd["key"].substring(0,items[i].value.Zd["key"].length-1) == keys[j].split("|")[1]){
            items[i].value.Zd["key"] = keys[j].split("|")[1];
        }
    }   
    console.log(strVal + "----->" + items[i].value.Zd["key"]);
}
```

/* Trying to reset the canvas content */

```
for (i = 0; i < c.childElementCount; i++) {
        if (c.children[i].nodeName == "CANVAS") {
            /*c.removeChild(c.children[i]);
            var newcanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            newcanvas.id="canvas1";
            newcanvas.getContext = new_cv;
            c.appendChild(newcanvas);*/
            //cHeight = c.children[i].height;
            //cWidth = c.children[i].width;
            //cv.clearRect(0,0,c.children[i].width,c.children[i].height);
            //c.children[i] = new_cv;
            //cv.setContext(new_cv);

            canv.getContext = new_cv;
            console.log(cv);
        }
}
```

is there any way I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally you do not delete a canvas node. Deleting is expensive. Generally you clear the context using `ctx.clearRect()`or `ctxfillRect()` and next you draw the modified content.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding back. clearRect or fillRect has no effect on it. And how can I set the modified content back to the canvas.

Comment: Please build a working snippet that can be run in Stack Overflow, & I'll try to help.

Comment: Below fiddle link. Where I tried to change the color of the rectangle from red to black and re-assigned to canvas

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/santhu1605/rshj2bg1/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is this:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

ctx.clearRect(0,0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
<p id="cont"> FillStyle Content</p>
```

However if you want to use pixel manipulation (much more expensive) you can do this:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);

var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
// for every pixel if the red channel value is 255 (i.e. red) then make it black (0)
for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
  if (imgData.data[i + 0] == 255) {
    imgData.data[i + 0] = 0;
  }
}
// put the modified image back
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
<p id="cont"> FillStyle Content</p>
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for you help Enxaneta